# R vlookup combinded with if...and

Tags: r, if-statement, lookup

as a beginner to R, I'm facing troubles with a complex issue, for my side.

I want to add a new column with a "1" when the data$Date is between/exactly the lookup$Begin and lookup$End. Identification_no is the key for both data sets.
If the data$date is not bewteen lookup$Begin and lookup$End then there should a "0" in the new data column.

Both data frames have different length of observations.

Here's my basic data frame:

```
> data
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Date       Identification_no
* <date>                 <dbl>
1 2018-08-25                13
2 2018-02-03                54
3 2018-09-01                31
4 2018-11-10                54
5 2018-08-04                60
6 2018-07-07                58
```

Here's my lookup data frame:

```
> lookup
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Begin      End        Identification_no
* <date>     <date>                 <dbl>
1 2017-01-26 2017-01-26                53
2 2017-01-26 2017-01-26                53
3 2017-01-26 2017-01-26                53
4 2017-01-26 2017-01-26                53
5 2017-01-26 2017-01-26                53
6 2017-01-26 2017-01-26                53
```

Thanks for your inputs in advance.

---

EDIT: new sample data

```
> data
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Date       Identification_no
  <date>                 <dbl>
1 2018-08-25                13
2 2018-02-03                54
3 2018-09-01                31
4 2018-11-10                54
5 2018-08-04                60
6 2018-07-07                58

> lookup
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Begin      End        Identification_no
  <date>     <date>                 <dbl>
1 2018-08-20 2018-08-27                13
2 2018-09-01 2018-09-08                53
3 2018-01-09 2018-01-23                20
4 2018-10-16 2018-10-30                 4
5 2017-12-22 2017-12-29                54
6 2017-10-31 2017-11-07                66
```

Result through below described method:

```
> final
        Begin        End Identification_no match_col
1: 2018-08-25 2018-08-25                13         1
2: 2018-02-03 2018-02-03                54         0
3: 2018-09-01 2018-09-01                31         0
4: 2018-11-10 2018-11-10                54         0
5: 2018-08-04 2018-08-04                60         0
6: 2018-07-07 2018-07-07                58         0
```

Works perfectly fine - thanks for your solution.

Best regards,
Paul

Comment: This is a good example of "a mostly-reproducible question, but the sample data does nothing". If @arg0naut's answer is good, then accept it, otherwise please edit your question and provide sample data that actually matches.

Comment: Why would `lookup` have same entries repeated? Shouldn't it have only unique entries? Also you do know that your `Begin` and `End` dates are the same ?

Comment: @r2evans  thank you for advise. Abosluety correct, that the sample data are not representative. Therefore I've added new one, hoping to create clearity for the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could do:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)[, Date := as.Date(Date)]
setDT(lookup)[, `:=` (Begin = as.Date(Begin), End = as.Date(End), match_col = 1)]

final <- unique(lookup, by = c("Begin", "End","Identification_no"))[
  data, on = .(Begin <= Date, End >= Date, Identification_no)][
  is.na(match_col), match_col := 0]
```

On your example dataset, this would give:

```
final

        Begin        End Identification_no match_col
1: 2018-08-25 2018-08-25                13         0
2: 2018-02-03 2018-02-03                54         0
3: 2018-09-01 2018-09-01                31         0
4: 2018-11-10 2018-11-10                54         0
5: 2018-08-04 2018-08-04                60         0
6: 2018-07-07 2018-07-07                58         0
```

.. but only because there's really no match.

Comment: When I'm using the solution at my real data, it deliveres following:

"Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 4877597 rows; more than 3453517 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE."

Is that because I've 3.5 Mio. data-objectives. vs 50K lookup-objectives?
What can I do here?

Comment: Try adding `allow.cartesian=TRUE` at the end of 2nd line, like `.(Begin <= Date, End >= Date, Identification_no), allow.cartesian = TRUE]`